# How to create nested list from hierarchy

Tags: python, django, data-structures

I have some UserInvites, where an invite has `from` and `to` User properties.

E.g.,

```
UserInvite1.from = User1
UserInvite1.to = User2

UserInvite1b.from = User1
UserInvite1b.to = User4

UserInvite2.from = User2
UserInvite2.to = User3

UserInvite3.from = User2
UserInvite3.to = User5
```

Thus, User1 invited User2 and User4; User2 invited User3 and User5.

Given a list of those invites, e.g., `[UserInvite1, UserInvite2, ... ]`, **or another means of iterating over them**(?), how can I generate a "hierarchical" (nested) list representing those invited?

E.g., starting with the "root" User1, I'd like a nested list as such:

```
>>> make_nest_list_from_invites([invites])
[User1, [User2, [User3, User5], User4]]
```

If you're familiar with Django, I'm trying to get from my "invites" to something hierarchical that I can feed to the Django template tag [unordered_list](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#unordered-list)

Clearly this is something like tree traversal, but I'm stumped at the moment. I tried some recursion-ey stuff, but kept ending up with an extra level of nesting in places that was throwing things off.

## UPDATE: Example of something I tried

```
def tree_from_here(user):
    children = get_children(user)
    if children:
        return [user, [tree_from_here(c) for c in children]]
    else:
        return user
```

Which gives:

```
>>> tree_from_here(User1)
[<User: 1>, [[<User: 2>, [<User: 3>, <User: 5>]], <User: 4>]]
```

Which is almost correct for my current set of users, *with the exception* that the nesting goes too deep in the second element.

I am trying for:

```
[<User: 1>, [<User: 2>, [<User: 3>, <User: 5>], <User: 4>]]
```

I feel like it's staring me in the face, but I am not sure how to return the right thing at the moment.

Comment: You've got a good idea of it - do a traversal of each user invited by the current user, then recursion over each user invited by those users, with a stopping condition of: when the `to` user is the same root user you started with or `None`.

Comment: Wouldn't you need the head of the tree?

Comment: @StephenRauch Are you asking me or @Taylor?

Comment: I was thinking the root of the tree could either be relative (e.g., a user ID of interest) or absolute (e.g., the first user).  I'm not sure the latter would work though: What if the first user invited no one and the second user joined without a referral?  Perhaps a root node doesn't make sense here and this is more of a graph than a tree.

Comment: @TaylorEdmiston There is a concept of root, and no user without an invite from another. Thanks for trying to explain. What you described earlier appears to be how I say it out loud -- but putting the code together for the "then recursion over each invited..." is where I'm stumbling. I'll post an update and example of progress shortly.

Comment: i think you forgot to update the sample data - there is no invite for user 5

Comment: @wiesion I see that my change wasn't explicit enough, tho I was hoping it would pass with understanding. Updating it now.

Comment: just needed to know who invited 5 :) but i am wondering: your system of invites has only one single "root" inviter? what if you need to fetch the entire structure of invites and let's say user1 and user2 are root users who invited a lot of people?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a hard time understanding your idea about this represantation of a nested structure, but after a lot of thinking and writing code i am confident that i understand, so i guess this is what you are after - description within the code and online demo here: https://repl.it/repls/EarlyWeeklyThings - was a nice challenge, thx :)

```
from pprint import pprint

# dummy user class
class User(object):
  def __init__(self, user_id):
    self.user_id = user_id
  def __repr__(self):
    return "User{}".format(self.user_id)

# dummy invite class 
class UserInvite(object):
  def __init__(self, from_user, to_user):
    self.from_user = from_user
    self.to_user = to_user
  def __repr__(self):
    return "From {} to {}".format(self.from_user, self.to_user)

# create 10 dummy users to create invites
users = [User(user_id) for user_id in range(1,11)]

# use natural numbers to reflect invites
# adjust in list comprehension
invite_map = (
  (1, 3), (1, 5), 
  (2, 4), (2, 6),
  (3, 7), (3, 8),
  (4, 9),
  (9, 10)
)

# create invitations based on the invite_map, fix natural numbers
example_invites = [
  UserInvite(users[inviter-1], users[invitee-1]) for inviter, invitee in invite_map
]

pprint(example_invites)
# =>
# [From User1 to User3,
#  From User1 to User5,
#  From User2 to User4,
#  From User2 to User6,
#  From User3 to User7,
#  From User3 to User8,
#  From User4 to User9,
#  From User9 to User10]

def get_nested_invites(invites, invited_by=None):
  result = []
  if not invited_by:
    # Assume that initial inviters were not invited by anyone
    # Use set comprehensions to avoid duplicates and for performance
    invitees = {invite.to_user for invite in invites}
    inviters = {invite.from_user for invite in invites if invite.from_user not in invitees}
  else:
    # Get the next potential inviters given their inviter
    # Use set comprehension to avoid duplicates and for performance
    inviters = {invite.to_user for invite in invites if invite.from_user == invited_by}
  for inviter in inviters:
    # Add the invited user/potential inviter 
    result.append(inviter)
    # Let's get nesty
    invitees = get_nested_invites(invites, inviter)
    if invitees:
      result.append(invitees)
  return result

pprint(get_nested_invites(example_invites))
# =>
# [User1,
#  [User3, [User7, User8], User5],
#  User2,
#  [User6, User4, [User9, [User10]]]]

pprint(get_nested_invites(example_invites, users[1]))
# =>
# [User6, User4, [User9, [User10]]]
```

Comment: Thanks so much! Your approach does exactly what I desired! As you can see from my most recent "what I tried" bit: I was attempting to start at a User, and use a utility (get_children) to go down from there. Starting at the invites, as you did (and I mentioned in the original question) works fine! Thanks again!

Comment: yw! If i may add, if you're going to use this productively with a lot of invites, you should probably subtract the invites covered by `inviters` before passing them to the nested call to avoid overhead lookups